# How to Convert an ArrayList to string C#

Tags: string, c#-4.0, arraylist

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
string abc =
```

What should I do to convert arraylist to a string such as abc = arr;
**Updated Quest**Other consideration from which i can complete my work is concatination of string(need help in that manner ). suppose i have a 
string s="abcdefghi.."
by applying foreach loop on it and getting char by matching some condition and concatinating every char value in some insatnce variable of string type 
i.e string subString=+;
Something like this
`string tem = string.Empty;
            string temp =string.Empty;
            temp = string.Concat(tem,temp);`

Comment: What do you want the string to contain? The string representation of every element in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: i supplied value of char type to my arrraylist from some loop. Now i want to assign that arraylist collection to string abc

Comment: @Gimmebrkk Although it should have been a separate question, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Does anyone understand what OP wants?

Comment: @DanielMošmondor The ability to join an `ArrayList` of `char`s into a single string, and a way to concatenate a series of strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a little linq and making the assumption that your `ArrayList` contains `string` types:

```
using System.Linq;

var strings = new ArrayList().Cast<string>().ToArray();

var theString = string.Join(" ", strings);
```

Further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

For converting other types to string:

```
var strings = from object o in myArrayList
              select o.ToString();

var theString = string.Join(" ", strings.ToArray());
```

The first argument to the `Join` method is the separator, I chose whitespace. It sounds like your chars should all contribute without a separator, so use `""` or `string.Empty` instead.

**Update:** if you want to concatenate a small number of strings, the `+=` operator will suffice:

```
var myString = "a";
myString += "b"; // Will equal "ab";
```

However, if you are planning on concatenating an indeterminate number of strings in a tight loop, use the `StringBuilder`:

```
using System.Text;

var sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sb.Append("a");
}

var myString = sb.ToString();
```

This avoids the cost of lots of string creations due to the immutability of strings.

Comment: read the updated quest. here i want to concatinate two string

Comment: @Gimmebrkk Read my updated answer, I've demonstrated how to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2):

Look into `string.Join()`, the opposite of `string.Split()`

You'll also need to convert your `arr` to `string[]`, I guess that `ToArray()` will help you do that.

Comment: read the updated quest. here i want to concatinate two string

Answer (score 0):

Personally and for memory preservation I’ll do for a concatenation:

```
        System.Collections.ArrayList Collect = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        string temporary = string.Empty;
        Collect.Add("Entry1");
        Collect.Add("Entry2");
        Collect.Add("Entry3");

        foreach (String var in Collect)
        {
            temporary = temporary + var.ToString();  
        }
        textBox1.Text = temporary;
```

Comment: You don't want to concatenate strings like this, as it requires reallocating |temporary| on every iteration. Use StringBuilder instead.